# Java implementing swing api, instance of object JButton not recognized

Tags: java, swing

I have a very simple and small java program using the swing libraries to create a static stop watch. Problem being, whenever I try to compile it at the command line with "javac program.java" it seems to give a series of errors as if the statements related to the object button were not recognized by the compiler.

---

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;

class StopWatch implements ActionListener {

    JLabel jlab;
    long start;  // holds the start time in milliseconds

    StopWatch() {
        // Create a new JFrame Container.
        JFrame jfrm = new JFrame("A Simple StopWatch");

        // Specify the FlowLayout for the layout manager.
        jfrm.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        // Give the frame an initial size.
        jfrm.setSize(230,90);

        // Terminates the program when the user closes the application.
        jfrm.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        // Make two buttons
        JButton JbtnStart = new JButton("Start");
        JButton JbtnStop = new JButton("Stop");

        // Add action listeners. 
        jbtnStart.addActionListener(this);
        jbtnStop.addActionListener(this);

        // Add the buttons to the content pane
        jfrm.add(jbtnStart); 
        jfrm.add(jbtnStop);

        // Create a text-based label
        jlab = new JLabel("Press Start to begin timing.");

        // Add the label
        jfrm.add(jlab);

        jfrm.setVisible(true);

    }

    // Handle button events
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();  // get current system time

        if (ae.getActionCommand().equals("Start")) { 
            start = cal.getTimeInMillis();
            jlab.setText("Stopwatch is Running...");
        }

        else
            // Compute the elapsed time.
            jlab.setText("Elapsed time is "+(double)(cal.getTimeInMillis() - start)/1000);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() { new StopWatch(); }
        });
    }

}
```

---

The following are the error messages:

```
StopWatch.java:30: error: cannot find symbol
jbtnStart.addActionListener(this);
        ^
Symbol:   variable jbtnStart
location: class StopWatch
StopWatch.java:31: error: cannot find symbol
jbtnStop.addActionListener(this);
        ^
symbol:   variable jbtnStop
location: class StopWatch
StopWatch.java:34: error: cannot find symbol
jfrm.add(jbtnStart); 
                 ^
symbol:   variable jbtnStart
location: class StopWatch
StopWatch.java:35: error: cannot find symbol
jfrm.add(jbtnStop);
                     ^
symbol:   variable jbtnStop
location: class StopWatch
4 errors
```

Would jbtnStop and jbtnStart be reserved words in the java language?

Comment: `JButton JbtnStart` and then you're trying to use `jbtnStart` ...

Comment: `JbtnStart != jbtnStart`, one starts with an upper case letter, the other does not, and Java is a case sensitive language. i.e. `jbtnStart` has not be declared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made changes to your code just changed `JbtnStart` with `jbtnStart` 
and `JbtnStop` with `jbtnStop`

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;

class StopWatch implements ActionListener {

    JLabel jlab;
    long start;  // holds the start time in milliseconds

    StopWatch() {
        // Create a new JFrame Container.
        JFrame jfrm = new JFrame("A Simple StopWatch");

        // Specify the FlowLayout for the layout manager.
        jfrm.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        // Give the frame an initial size.
        jfrm.setSize(230,90);

        // Terminates the program when the user closes the application.
        jfrm.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        // Make two buttons
        JButton jbtnStart = new JButton("Start");
        JButton jbtnStop = new JButton("Stop");

        // Add action listeners. 
        jbtnStart.addActionListener(this);
        jbtnStop.addActionListener(this);

        // Add the buttons to the content pane
        jfrm.add(jbtnStart); 
        jfrm.add(jbtnStop);

        // Create a text-based label
        jlab = new JLabel("Press Start to begin timing.");

        // Add the label
        jfrm.add(jlab);

        jfrm.setVisible(true);

    }

    // Handle button events
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();  // get current system time

        if (ae.getActionCommand().equals("Start")) { 
            start = cal.getTimeInMillis();
            jlab.setText("Stopwatch is Running...");
        }

        else
            // Compute the elapsed time.
            jlab.setText("Elapsed time is "+(double)(cal.getTimeInMillis() - start)/1000);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() { new StopWatch(); }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, I can see the obvious error due to the mismatch of cases now.

Comment: @user3719700 if you got your answer kindly accept this as answer thank you. Plus i recommend you to use IDE like net beans,eclipse,intellij Idea etc (if not beginner)

Answer (score 1):

Fix these variables names:

```
JButton JbtnStart = new JButton("Start");
JButton JbtnStop = new JButton("Stop");
```

They should start from small letter:

```
JButton jbtnStart = new JButton("Start");
JButton jbtnStop = new JButton("Stop");
```

Java is a case-sensitive language, so you should be careful with naming

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That was a silly mistake. I should use an IDE instead vi

Answer (score 0):

```
JbtnStart != jbtnStart
```

Java is a case sensitive language.

Comment: I realize that they are not equal. One simply did not notice the lower and upper case letters difference on screen.